# Divisibility of a binomial coefficient with a prime

Tags: number-theory

I wondered why the expression $$ \binom {2n}{n} $$ is always divisible by each prime p with $$ n < p \leq 2n $$

Now I wanted to proof this but I don't know where I should start...

I can rewrite the expression to:
$$ \binom {2n}{n} = \frac{(2n!)}{n!\cdot(2n-n)!}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$$
but I dont think, that this will really help, so i hope that someone can help me!

Thanks! :)

Comment: for the number is an integer, and the denominator doesn't contain any prime from $n$ to $2n.$

Answer (score 3):

- Every prime $n<p<2n$ divides to $(2n)!$ because is a factor
- if $p$ is prime, and $n<p$, $n!$ is not a multiple of $p$ because every divisor $d$ of $n!$ is $d\leq n <p$ ie, $d\neq p$

Then $(2n)!/n!^2$ is multiple of $p$

Comment: mhh, this was a bit too fast... I have'nt understood it :/

Comment: could you maybe explain it again, a little more detailed, please?

Comment: @Niklas I just edit

Comment: Thanks, but I dont get the step from the two points to the $$(2n)!/n!^2$$...
I think I have blackout but I cant get it... :D

Comment: Suppose $p$ is prime and $n<p<2n$. Then $$(2n)!=1\cdot 2\cdot\cdots\cdot (n-1)\cdot n\cdot\cdots\cdot p\cdot\cdots\cdot (2n-1)\cdot2n.$$

Comment: This part I understand, but why do I need:
$\begin{multline}
\\
\end{multline}$
    "- if $p$ is prime, and $n<p$, $n!$ is not a multiple of $p$ because every divisor $d$ of $n!$ is $d\leq n <p$ ie, $d\neq p$"
$\begin{multline}
\\
\end{multline}$
??

Comment: @Laars Helenius,
$\begin{multline}
\\
\end{multline}$
Could someone maybe explain, why I need the info: $d /=p$?

Comment: @Niklas The idea is: suppose that n! is a multiple of p. but i proved that every divisor d of n! Is <p then p is not a divisor of n!

Comment: Mhh, okay... I do not really understsand it but I think I simply accept it.. :/

Comment: Wait, maybe I understand it, if you explain to me, why I have to proof, that n" is not a multiple of p...

Answer (score 0):

Consider any prime $p\le n$. Then $p$ is a factor of both $n!$ and $(2n)!$, say $n!=p\cdot k$ and $(2n)!=p\cdot 2p\cdot \ell$. Then
$$
\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=\frac{p\cdot 2p\cdot \ell}{p^2\cdot k^2}=\frac{2\ell}{k^2}
$$
so it is not clear if $p$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$ when $p\le n$. However, if $n<p<2n$, then $n!$ cannot have the prime $p$ as a factor as all factors of $n!$ that are greater than $n$ must be composite.